# Displaying dialogs, layouts and data filtering in MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I start my adventure with MVVM architecture and have encountered several situations where I can't find a definite answer.

1. Display for example AlertDialog. I am currently displaying the AlertDialog from the activity (view) because ViewModel should not hold any reference to the view. Is this the right mechanism?
2. Recently, I was making an application in which I got all tasks from the database. Tasks were divided into 3 categories and I needed to put tasks from each category in a separate list. I did it as follows in activity (view):

   ```
   viewModelMainActivity = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelMainActivity.class);
   viewModelMainActivity.getAllTasks().observe(this, new Observer<List<Task>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(List<Task> tasks) {

           List<Task> allJobTasks = new ArrayList<>();
           List<Task> allShoppingTasks = new ArrayList<>();
           List<Task> allOtherTasks = new ArrayList<>();

           for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i ++) {

               String category = tasks.get(i).getCategory();

               switch (category) {
                   case JOB_CATEGORY:
                       allJobTasks.add(tasks.get(i));
                       break;

                   case SHOPPING_CATEGORY:
                       allShoppingTasks.add(tasks.get(i));
                       break;

                   case OTHER_CATEGORY:
                       allOtherTasks.add(tasks.get(i));
                       break;

               }
           }

           taskAdapter.setAllJobTasks(allJobTasks);
           taskAdapter.setAllShoppingTasks(allShoppingTasks);
           taskAdapter.setAllOtherTasks(allOtherTasks);

           showOrHideImageAndText(allJobTasks, JOB_CATEGORY);
           showOrHideImageAndText(allShoppingTasks, SHOPPING_CATEGORY);
           showOrHideImageAndText(allOtherTasks, OTHER_CATEGORY);

           taskAdapter.setCurrentTasks(currentCategory);

       }
   });
   ```

Is this the right way? I don't think so, but how else could I filter data by category?

Answer (score 0):

Answering both questions

1.- It is correct that you do it in the activity, because otherwise you would have to send the activity reference to the view model

2.- As I can assume in your code, you use those lists later to fill a view, the correct thing would be to do the filling of the lists in the view model before returning the response to the activity, but not being such a heavy logic as information management I don't see it 100% necessary, so its ok to do it in the activity